# Open XML Format not working

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm trying to format an Excel sheet. The header should have bold font and orange background. When I open the sheet, Excel gives me an error saying the document is invalid, and it open with all cells bold and no background in the header.

This is how a set the style.

.....

```
workbookStylePart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
workbookStylePart.Stylesheet = CreateStylesheet();
workbookStylePart.Stylesheet.Save();
.....
cell.StyleIndex = 0U; // I suppose the style index is 0
```

This the style definition:

```
    private static Stylesheet CreateStylesheet()
    {
        Stylesheet stylesheet = new Stylesheet() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "x14ac" } };
        stylesheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
        stylesheet.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14ac", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac");

        Fonts fonts = new Fonts() { Count = 1U, KnownFonts = true };
        Font boldFont = new Font();
        Bold bold = new Bold();
        boldFont.Append(bold);

        fonts.Append(boldFont);

        Fills fills = new Fills() { Count = 1U };

        // FillId = 0, orange
        Fill orangeFill = new Fill();
        PatternFill orangePatternFill = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
        BackgroundColor orangeColor = new BackgroundColor() { Rgb = "FFA500" };
        orangePatternFill.Append(orangeColor);
        orangeFill.Append(orangePatternFill);

        fills.Append(orangeFill);

        CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats() { Count = 1U };
        CellFormat headerBoldOrangeBgFormat = new CellFormat() { FontId = 0U, FillId = 0U , ApplyFill = true};

        cellFormats.Append(headerBoldOrangeBgFormat);

        stylesheet.Append(fonts);
        stylesheet.Append(fills);
        stylesheet.Append(cellFormats);

        return stylesheet;
    }
```

Comment: Have you ran the [OpenXml productivity tool?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) This should help you identify what is breaking your excel file.

Comment: No, I haven't. I didn't know about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClosedXML library is a high-level wrapper over OpenXML. I recommend that you use ClosedXML. In addition, there is a ClosedXML.Report library that generates an Excel file based on the XLSX-template.

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Report

Comment: I had an implementation with Interop, but because of technnical issues with that, I changed to Open XML. I was able to reuse my old code. It was just necessary made some adjusts, but it really saved my week. So I will accept this as a valid answer